# TYPO3 Missing FE-Users and Inserting new Website User disappeared from list

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

In the backend of my TYPO3 CMS, all front-end users have disappeared from the folder they usually reside in. Front-end usergroups are still there. Also, if I want to add a new Website User, the Website User element is missing from the list (see image).

[image: No Website User available anylonger]

I have to admit that I have been playing around with extending the fe_user table a bit, but to my knowledge all I have done is adding one field in the fe_user table using phpMyAdmin. Removing this field didn't solve the problem of the entirely missing frond-end users however.

P.s. I already ran the Install Tool database comparison and upgrade scripts...

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:

I had a custom extension where - in ext_tables.php - I had a line:

```
$TCA['tx_myext_domain_model_fe_users'] = array(...)
```

overwriting the default fe_users TCA contents... Removing this part solved the issue.